# Select special characteres mysql

Tags: mysql

I need to make selects from fields that can contain special characteres for example

```
+--------------+
| code         |
+--------------+
| **4058947"_\ |
| **4123/"_\   |
| sew'-8947"_\ |
+--------------+
```

i try this

```
select code from table where code REGEXP '[(|**4058947"_\|)]'; 
select code from table where code REGEXP '[(**4058947"_\)]';
select code from table where code REGEXP '^[(**4058947"_\)]';
```

but the querys return all rows and this query return empty

```
select code from table where code REGEXP '^[(**4058947"_\)]$';
```

and i need that only return the first one or the specified

Comment: In a regexp, mostly backslashes are special characters. What if you use `\\` (a double backslash) instead of a single?

Comment: the backslash is part of the field in the code name

Comment: Yes, I saw that. But the regular expression you used in your SQL statements are probably not working because the backslash is the escape character (like in Java/PHP/JavaScript), so you should escape it itself. Also, you have other special characters in the code fields which should be escaped in the regex. (Namely `*`, `| `, `(` and `)`).

Comment: Sorry, most of those special characters are only in your regexes, not in the actual fields. Why all the parentheses, brackets and pipes (| symbols)?

Comment: Why do you want to use regular expressions for selecting the record?

Comment: well that simbols are for regexp or rlike, but if theres other way to get the data it will be fine

Answer (score 0):

To select only one row, you could just do this if it doesn't matter which one.

```
SELECT code FROM table LIMIT 1
```

If it *does* matter, drop the regex.

```
SELECT code FROM table WHERE code = "**4058947\"_\\"
```

To match those special characters (in this case, `"` and `\`), you need to "escape" them. (That's how it's called. I didn't make that up.) In most mainstream languages this is done by putting a backslash in front of it (MySQL does it this way too). The backslash is the *escape character*, a backslash with another character behind it is called an *escape sequence*. As you see, I escaped the quote and the backslash in the code value I want to match, so it should work now.

---

If you need to keep the regexes (which I hope is not the case, since you have the literal string you want to match against) same thing applies. Escape quotes and backslashes and you'll be fine, if you drop the parentheses and brackets. Note that in a regex, you need to escape far more characters. This is because some characters (for example: `| [] () * +` have a special function in a regex. This is very handy, but becomes a bit of a problem when you need to match a string with that character in it. In that case, you need to escape it, but with a double backslash! This is because MySQL first parses the query and will throw an error if it encounters an invalid escape sequence (that is, if you escape a character you needn't escape according to MySQL). Only then is the result parsed as a regex, with the double backslashes replaced by single backslashes. This gets ugly very quickly, since this means matching a backslash with a MySQL regex requires 4 backslashes! Two in the regex, but this needs to be doubled, since MySQL parses it as a string first!